# How to Stream audio from Microphone Using gstreamer over a network

Tags: gstreamer

i want to stream audio input from my mic on my system over a network , i know how to record audio from mic but stuck with streaming it over a network.
here pipeline for recording from my microphone
**gst-launch -v alsasrc device=hw 0 ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! oggmux ! filesink location=alsasrc1112.ogg**

Comment: server side 'code'
gst-launch v4l2src ! ffmpegcolorspace ! tee name=tee0 ! queue !  autovideosink tee0. ! queue ! theoraenc  ! mux. alsasrc device=hw 0 ! audioconvert ! queue ! vorbisenc  ! mux. oggmux name=mux ! queue ! tcpserversink host=localhost port=5000

Comment: gst-launch tcpclientsrc host=localhost port=5000 ! oggdemux name=d d.  ! queue  ! theoradec ! autovideosink d. ! queue ! vorbisdec ! audioconvert ! alsasink sync=false

Comment: these are two pipelines can any1 test em for me i dont have a mic .  the first one is server and second client. thanks and please reply with result